# MVC - Getting ViewModel object from ListBoxFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get my own viewmodel after submit my form and I got the following error:
"Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[]' to type 'System.String'"

This is my code:

**ViewMode:**

```
public class SoftwarePackages
{
 public string[] PermissionsList { get; set; }
}
```

**aspx**

```
<%: Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.PermissionsList, new List<SelectListItem>(), new { size = 10 })%>
```

**controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SoftwarePackages softwarePackages)
{
  code...code...code
}
```

what is the problem?

Thank you

zurdoIL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following works fine for me:

Model:

```
public class SoftwarePackages
{
    public string[] PermissionsList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new SoftwarePackages
        {
            Items = new SelectList(new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "item 1" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "item 2" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "item 3" },
            }, "Value", "Text")
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SoftwarePackages softwarePackages)
    {
        // do something with softwarePackages.PermissionsList
        ...
    }
}
```

View:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%: Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.PermissionsList, Model.Items, new { size = 10 })%>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem:

In my viewmodel I had the following attributes:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide a Description!")]
[StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Description must be less than 255 characters!")]
[DisplayName("Description")]
```

and of course the "StringLength" attribute was which was try to cast this field to string.

Thank you for your help!

zurdoIL

Answer (score 0):

As an aside you will not be able to get your model back with the code you've shown.  The the `ListBoxFor` (and `DropDownListFor`) helper methods use that `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` to actually render their contents, and you are passing an empty collection of `SelectListItems` into the method.  You can use these extension methods to create an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from any `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
public static class IEnumerableStringExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItemList(this IEnumerable<string> items)
    {
        return IEnumerableStringExtensions.ToSelectListItemList(items, new List<string>());
    }

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItemList(this IEnumerable<string> items, string selectedValue)
    {
        return IEnumerableStringExtensions.ToSelectListItemList(items, new List<string>());
    }

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItemList(this IEnumerable<string> items, IEnumerable<string> selectedValues)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> listitems = new List<SelectListItem>(items.Count());

        foreach (string s in items)
        {
            listitems.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = s,
                Value = s,
                Selected = selectedValues.Contains(s)
            });
        }

        return listitems;
    }
}
```

Use the methods like this:

```
<%:Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.PermissionList, Model.PermissionList.ToSelectListItemList(), new { size = 10 })%>
```

Using a sample project I was not able to duplicate your exception from the code you have provided (`PermissionList` was just null), but at least the class above will get your model back to the server (more accurately the values that the user selected from the list).